# Unable to install the latest version of image_picker in a Flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image-picker

I installed [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) in my Flutter app through `$ flutter pub add image_picker`.
Currently, the latest version is [1.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker/versions/1.0.1), but in my `pubspec.yaml` file i get version [0.7.2+1](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker/versions/0.7.2+1).

Since *"Starting with version 0.8.2 of the image_picker plugin, new methods have been added"* (e.g. `ImagePicker().getImage(...)` is now `ImagePicker().pickImage(...)`), I can't use these methods.

I tried to manually change the version to 1.0.1, but when I run `$ flutter pub get` I get the following error:

```
Because image_picker >=1.0.1 depends on image_picker_for_web ^2.2.0 which depends on flutter_web_plugins from sdk, image_picker >=1.0.1 requires flutter_web_plugins from sdk.
So, because flutter_web_plugins from sdk doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_web_plugins in the Flutter SDK) and my_app depends on image_picker ^1.0.1, version solving failed.
exit code 69
```

Here is my `pubspec.yaml` file after creating the app with `$ flutter create my_app` and adding the dependency with `$ flutter pub add image_picker`:

```
name: my_app
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.7.2+1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Which flutter version are you using?

Comment: @RohitSuthar I was using version 3.10.5. I've upgraded it to version 3.10.6 with `$ flutter upgrade` and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message kinda clear. You could do this 2 solutions:

- Upgrade Flutter to use the latest Flutter version, which exists `flutter_web_plugins` inside that.
- Just use the old version of `image_picker` that doesn't requires `flutter_web_plugins`.

If you're maintaining old project & don't care/want to use latest version, use solution 2.